# In Ant Design, how can we center an icon vertically in <Row>?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, antd

Please see my React code example:

```
import { Row, Col, Icon } from 'antd';
const MyRow = () => (
  <Row align="middle">
    <Col md={10}>Trouble is a friend</Col>
    <Col md={10}><Icon type="play-circle-o" /></Col>
    <Col md={4}><div>Lenka</div></Col>
  </Row>
);

...
```

When I rendered `<MyRow />`, I found that the text in `<Row>` was centered vertically well, but the `<Icon>` component didn't do so. So that my `<MyRow>` didn't look good. I expected all the content, not only the text but also the `SVG` in `<Row>` could be centered vertically.

I also tried other icon library, e.g. `react-icons-kit`, which did not work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fortunately, I found some solutions to this small problem myself.

For icons in `@ant-design/icons`:

```
import { PlayCircleFilled } from '@ant-design/icons';

<Row align="middle">
  <Col>
    <PlayCircleFilled
      style={{
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
      }}
    />
  </Col>
</Row>
```

For icons in `react-icons`:

```
import { RiVolumeUpLine } from "react-icons/ri";

<Row align="middle">
  <Col>
    <RiVolumeUpLine
      style={{
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
      }}
    />
  </Col>
</Row>
```

For `Icon` in **old** `antd`:

```
<Row type="flex" align="middle">
  <Col>
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'inline-flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Icon
        type="play-circle-o"
        style={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

For `Icon` in `react-icons-kit`:

```
import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
import { ic_play_circle_outline } from 'react-icons-kit/md/ic_play_circle_outline';
...
<Row align="middle">
  <Col>
    <Icon icon={ic_play_circle_outline} style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }} />
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like we don't even need the `type="flex"` anymore (not even a prop anymore).

Answer (score 5):

This is not really antd specific, it's just about vertical centering in general.
I can recommend [6 Methods for Vertical Centering](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) which discusses ways to do it on traditional CSS. The CSS Table method should work well in this case.

You also achieve it using Flexbox (`<Row type="flex">`), with `align-items: center` for the row.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! I'm always afraid to write CSS. I tried `<Row type="flex" style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>` as you said and found it still didn't work.